# Can I make python use a previous definition of a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a simplified version of my problem

```
def findX():
    x = 2
    return x

def main():
    y = findX()
    y = y + 10
    #(unknown code here)
    print (y)


main()
```

I want the output to be:

```
2
```

Can I do this without subtracting 10 or without running findX() again? I think defining y = findX() as a global variable might work, but I would like to avoid global variables if possible.

Comment: Why not just assign the result to an extra variable *before* you alter `y`? No, there is no way to retrieve what a variable was referencing before.

Comment: Of course, the value you seek is still available by calling findX() again.  If that's what you want to retain, but maybe don't want to incur the cost of findX() (assuming it could be complex), you could cache the value within findX() itself.  Obviously, using an intermediate variable accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't.  When you assign a new value to `y`, it replaces the old value.

If you want to keep both values, assign the new one to a different variable:

```
y = findX()
z = y + 10
```

Comment: But there is "unknown code" between the assignment to y and the print statement.  Your solution causes y to have a different value that it previously did, and that could affect code inside the unknown block.  I don't know why you can't just move the print statement to the point where it's needed.